# Python migration from mysql to postgres - fk constraints not dropping

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, database-migration

I'm running a python script with sqlalchemy to export and then import data from production to a postgres db on a daily basis. The script runs successfully once and then the second time and beyond the script fails. As you will see in the script below, the error returned suggets the dependencies in the tables (foreign keys) are the cause of the import failure, however, I do not understand why this issue is not circumvented by the `sorted_tables` object. I've opted to remove any of the intialiation code like repoistory imports, db connection objects to simplify the post and reduce clutter.

```
def create_db(src,dst,src_schema,dst_schema,drop_dst_schema=False):
    if drop_dst_schema:
        post_db.engine.execute('DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS {0} CASCADE'.format(dst_schema))
        print "Schema {0} Dropped".format(dst_schema)
    post_db.engine.execute('CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS {0}'.format(dst_schema))
    post_db.engine.execute('GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA {0} TO {0}_ro'.format(dst_schema))
    post_db.engine.execute('GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA {0} TO {0}_rw'.format(dst_schema))
    print "Schema {0} Created".format(dst_schema)

def create_table(tbl, dst_schema):

    dest_table=tbl
    dest_table.schema=dst_schema
    for col in dest_table.columns:
        if hasattr(col.type, 'collation'):
            col.type.collation = None
        if col.name == 'id':
            dest_table.append_constraint(PrimaryKeyConstraint(col))
        col.type=convert(col.type)

    timestamp_col=Column ('timestamp',DateTime(timezone=False), server_default=func.now())
    #print tbl.c
    dest_table.append_column(timestamp_col)
    dest_table.create(post_db.engine,checkfirst=True)
    post_db.engine.execute('GRANT INSERT ON {1} to {0}_ro'.format(dst_schema, dest_table))
    post_db.engine.execute('GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON {1} to {0}_rw'.format(dst_schema, dest_table))
    print "Table {0} created".format(dest_table)

create_db(mysql_db.engine,post_db.engine,src_schema,dst_schema,drop_dst_schema=False)

mysql_meta=MetaData(bind=mysql_db.engine)
mysql_meta.reflect(schema=src_schema)

post_meta=MetaData(bind=post_db.engine)
post_meta.reflect(schema=dst_schema)

script_begin=time.time()
rejected_list=[]
for table in mysql_meta.sorted_tables:
    df=mysql_db.sql_retrieve('select * from {0}'.format(table.name))
    df=df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None)
    print "Table {0} : {1}".format(table.name,len(df))
    dest_table=table
    dest_table.schema = dst_schema
    dest_table.drop(post_db.engine, checkfirst=True)
    create_table(dest_table, dst_schema)
    print "Table {0} emptied".format(dest_table.name)
    try:
        start=time.time()
        if len(df)>10000:
            for g,df_new in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//10000):
                dict_items=df_new.to_dict(orient='records')
                post_db.engine.connect().execute(dest_table.insert().values(dict_items))
        else:
            dict_items=df.to_dict(orient='records')
            post_db.engine.connect().execute(dest_table.insert().values(dict_items))
        loadtime=time.time()-start
        print "Data loaded with datasize {0}".format(str(len(df)))
        print "Table {0} loaded to BI database with loadtime {1}".format(dest_table.name,loadtime)
    except:
        print "Table {0} could not be loaded".format(dest_table.name)
        rejected_list.append(dest_table.name)
```

If I drop the entire `dst_schema` before importing the data, the import succeeds.

This is the erorr I see:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (psycopg2.InternalError) cannot drop table A because other objects depend on it
DETAIL:  constraint fk_rails_111193 on table B depends on table A
HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
 [SQL: '\nDROP TABLE A']
```

Can someone steer me into a possible solution? 
Are there better alternatives other than dropping the `dst_schema` before importing the data to the destination db `(drop_dst_schema=true)`?

```
def create_db(src,dst,src_schema,dst_schema,drop_dst_schema=True)
```

Has anyone have an idea why `sorted_tables` does not drop the dependencies in the schema? Am I misunderstanding this object?

Comment: What approach did you end up using?

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

### Drop the whole schema every time

If you have a complex schema, with any kind of closed loop reference chain, your best option is to **always drop the whole schema**.

You could have some self-referencing tables (such as a `persons` table, with a self-relation of type `person parent-of person`). You could also have a schema where table A references table B which references table A. For instance, you have one table `persons` and one `companies`, and two relations (probably, with intermediat tables): `company employs persons`, and `persons trade shares of companies`.

In cases like this, that are realistic, no matter what you do with `sorted_tables`, this will never work.

If you're actually replicating data from another DB, and can afford the time, dropping and recreating the whole schema is the easiest to implement solution. Your code will be much simpler: less cases to consider.

### DROP CASCADE

You can also drop the tables using **`DROP CASCADE`**. If one table is referenced by another, this will drop both (or as many as necessary). You have to make sure the order in which you `DROP` and `CREATE` gives you the end result you expect. I'd check very carefully that this scenario works in all cases.

### Drop all FK constraints, then recreate them at the end

Also, there is also one last possibility: **drop all FK constraints for all tables** before manipulating them, and recreate them at the end. This way, you'll be able to drop any table at any moment.

Comment: thanks for the insights. I think the best options are dropping the schema entirely or dropping all FK constraints and the recreating them. `dst_schema = dst_schema.sorted_tables_constraints(mysql_meta.sorted_tables)` - this would be sufficient to drop all tables in schema or conversly to use the drop schema I described in the original post. Wouldn't this suffice in order to drop FK constraints `post_meta.drop_all(tables=mysql_meta.sorted_tables, checkfirst=True)` - before the loop retreiving data from mysql? I would love to hear if you have a better/cleaner sqlalchemy solution.

Comment: I'm not proficient with SQLAlchemy. I've never used it for this purpose. When I've needed something similary, I've always used `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` (or `pg_catalog`, if some "nitty-gritty" detail wasn't on the standard views); and plain SQL.